# Creating re-usable modules across different projects Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I'm creating an e-commerce using nuxtjs.
I wanted to create my application code reusable. So that I can use the same code in different E-commerce applications.

I realised most of the pages in E-commerce are same, except the presentation layer(which I assume is template section of nuxt). So I want to preserve the business logic and data layer. So my code can be reused.
I'm thinking about creating nuxt modules so that I can reuse functions.

Is this approach executable or is there any other approach.

Please let me know if you have done anything similar. Thank you

Comment: Hi! Did you found any solution? Can you please describe answer on you issue.